# Excel (no vba) givene a vector obtain a vector that is the result of applying a specific function to each element of the original one

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to obtain what I'm asking on the title without using vba?

For example:
The original vector is {1, 3, 5, 2, 8} (or a range of cells that contain those values) the function I want to apply is IF("<3", "a", "b")
I'm searching for a function that takes the vector and the operation like this:

```
=FUNCTION_I_SEARCH({1, 3, 5, 2, 8}, IF("<3", "a", "b"))
```

and produces as result {'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b'}

Comment: Wrap it in ARRAYTOTEXT: `=ARRAYTOTEXT (IF({1,3,5,2,8}<3,"'a'","'b'")` (untested)

Comment: `IF(YourArray<3,"a","b")` or what is it you are trying to do here?

Comment: @P.b actually I don't want a text, I want another array that I can use as an input for other array operations

Comment: @JvdV I tried the formula you wrote and it just returns 'a' and not an array

Comment: Well, then don't use ARRAYTOTEXT, just the IF

Comment: @user2572526 then you are using an older version of Excel and you'd need to confirm it as an array formula through ctrl shift enter

Answer (score 1):

### Create a Customized *Replace* Function Using `LAMBDA`

[image]

Create a name, e.g. `MyReplace`, and enter the following formula...

```
=LAMBDA(data,criteria,true_value,false_value,
MAP(data,LAMBDA(m,IF(COUNTIF(m,criteria),true_value,false_value))))
```

... in the ***RefersTo*** text box.

Now you can use the function anywhere (reasonably) in the workbook, e.g.:

```
=MyReplace(A2:B6,">3","'a'","'b'")
```

Comment: From how you describe it, it seems that the LAMBDA function should be exactly the function I was looking for! Unfortunately, it is not available on my Excel version. I guess it is a new function only available in Excel 365, is there a way to obtain the same in an older Excel version?